# Eclipse in WSL2: Context menus not scrollable

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, wsl-2

I am working with Debian in WSL2 with WSLg. I am using Eclipse 2023-03, actually Papyrus UML, if that matters.

WSL metadata is:

```
WSL version: 1.1.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.49
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to scroll context menus, which are too large to fit the screen:

[image: Unscrollable Eclipse context menu]

Any help appreciated ...